# Json mustache for loop range: 1 to 1000

Tags: javascript, json, loops, yaml, mustache

I am using .yaml and json.mustaches to build aws cloudformation templates.

I dont want to hardcode a list of 4040, 4041...etc 1000 times
Does mustache have concept of loop logic? ie I want a loop from 4040 to 5040. I imagine i could just specify start and end of the range and have the mustache generate the sequence.

desired output:

```
{
    "InstancePort": 4040,
    "LoadBalancerPort": 4040,
    "Protocol": "HTTPS", "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
},        
{
    "InstancePort": 4041,
    "LoadBalancerPort": 4041,
    "Protocol": "HTTPS", "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
},        
{
    "InstancePort": 4042,
    "LoadBalancerPort": 4042,
    "Protocol": "HTTPS", "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
}
```

...etc
till 5040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Section template, like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKYryJ):

```
{{#ports}}
{
  "InstancePort": {{port}},
  "LoadBalancerPort": {{port}},
  "Protocol": "HTTPS", "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
}   
{{/ports}}
```

And in your Javascript have the following data:

```
ports: [...Array(1000).keys()].map(i => { return { port: i + 4040 }});
```

The above ES6 map will generate 1000 numbers, starting at 4040 through to 5040.

Edit: Updated to include the correct attribute!

Comment: @tooptoop4 Unfortunately not. Mustache is logicless, meaning that it cannot perform its own logic. You need to provide data to a Mustache render function (like my codepen above).